# /dev/md0 changed to /dev/md127

Tags: linux, debian, mdadm

I have a *Debian* server (latest version and all security updates done) and 3 years ago I created a RAID-5 over 3 disks with `mdadm`. It still works but I now get an error from the tool `logwatch`. Just noticed it today so I do not know how long it is there. Also, there are no errors in any logfile. I use the whole RAID-5 in `lvm` so I do not see how I can use the solution given in "[My RAID 1 always renames itself to /dev/md127 after rebooting | DEBIAN 10](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/544841/my-raid-1-always-renames-itself-to-dev-md127-after-rebooting-debian-10)".

I also ran `update-initramfs -u` but this does not seem to solve the problem.

> mdadm: cannot open /dev/md0: No such file or directory

So I started to investigate and here are the things that I found.

```
root@horus:/etc# ls -lhd /dev/md*
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     60 19 dec 11:33 /dev/md
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 9, 127 19 dec 11:33 /dev/md127

root@horus:/etc# ls -lh /dev/md
totaal 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 19 dec 11:33 horus:0 -> ../md127

root@horus:/etc# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] 
md127 : active raid5 sdb1[3] sda1[0] sdd1[1]
      1953258496 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]
      bitmap: 3/8 pages [12KB], 65536KB chunk
unused devices: <none>

root@horus:/etc# mdadm -D /dev/md127
/dev/md127:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Tue Jan 26 11:57:52 2021
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 1953258496 (1862.77 GiB 2000.14 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 976629248 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
      Raid Devices : 3
     Total Devices : 3
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Wed Feb 28 10:05:57 2024
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 3
   Working Devices : 3
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : horus:0  (local to host horus)
              UUID : b187df52:41d7a47e:98e7fa00:cae9bf67
            Events : 23348

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
       1       8       49        1      active sync   /dev/sdd1
       3       8       17        2      active sync   /dev/sdb1

root@horus:/var/log# fdisk -l /dev/md127
Disk /dev/md127: 1,82 TiB, 2000136699904 bytes, 3906516992 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes / 1048576 bytes

root@horus:/etc# mdadm -D --scan
ARRAY /dev/md/horus:0 metadata=1.2 name=horus:0 UUID=b187df52:41d7a47e:98e7fa00:cae9bf67

root@horus:/etc# cat mdadm/mdadm.conf 
# mdadm.conf
#
# !NB! Run update-initramfs -u after updating this file.
# !NB! This will ensure that initramfs has an uptodate copy.
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY /dev/md0 level=raid5 num-devices=3 metadata=1.2 name=horus:0 UUID=b187df52:41d7a47e:98e7fa00:cae9bf67
   devices=/dev/sda1,/dev/sdb1,/dev/sdc1

# This configuration was auto-generated on Tue, 26 Jan 2021 11:39:42 +0100 by mkconf
```

What should I do? Can I change `md0` to `md127` in the `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` file? Should I only add the output of `mdadm -D --scan` to this file?

Comment: too much detail in mdadm.conf, just use UUID https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/703905/30851 https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/325519/30851 https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/533941/30851 also, use UUID in fstab/kernel parameters so you don't even rely on /dev/md - everything should work even if it appears under the wrong name

Comment: So I will leave it like it is. I checked the physical volume in lvm and there it uses `/dev/md127`. I will make a note and, if needed, I will replace the content of `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` file so it will point to `/dev/md127`.